# Uploaded file not shown in custom content type / Image not attached to content type

Tags: 7, media

In Drupal 7, I am trying to upload an image that belongs to a custom type.

I click the Browse button, choose the file and upload. Until there, all seems to work well.

[image: uploaded]

However, when I click next, instead of the add alt, title and text, I get only a screen that says Destination *, and with a Previous and Next buttons, as shown below. The save button is never displayed, and the image is not shown.

[image: what is this?]

However, the image is there if I check the files through the admin, moreover, all goes well If I add the image through the file/add, it is just in the custom type that I get the error.

I am logged in as an administrator and I have all the permissions checked in Media and File Entity

My files folder permissions are 755, and the javascript console shows:
'Attr.nodeValue' is deprecated. Please use 'value' instead. in jquery.js

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "about:blank" in 
browser?render=media-popup&types[]=image&activePlugins=&enabledPlugins=&schemes[]=public&schemes[]=…:92 (anonymous function)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update, this doesn't work with Image widget nor Media Browser widget. Same site works in PROD, I suppose it is something with the file system settings?

Answer (score 0):

These fixed it:

-I changed the content type to image instead of media browser.

-Reviewed the permissions for file and this particular content type.

-Changed the field display of the content type